# how to write a onfocus event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fied usernam having value = `'Your Name'`
After Validation of this fails it becomes : `'Enter Your Name'`

But I want that when I click this field or onfocus this `'Enter Your Name'` vanishes with `empty string.`

How to write on focus event in jquery?

Answer (score 2):

What you’re looking for has been standardized in HTML5 as [the `placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute). You should use this, and then use JavaScript to recreate this functionality for browsers who don’t support it natively yet.

Just write your HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

It will automatically work in modern browsers, no JavaScript required!

If you want to support older browsers, feel free to use my [Placeholder jQuery plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin), which will automatically make HTML like that work in every relevant browser. Just include the plugin and then go like:

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

…and the plugin will take care of the rest for you. You can view a demo here: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Answer (score 1):

```
$field.bind('focus.emptyfield', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Enter your name') {
    $(this).val('');
  }
}
```

assuming $field is your jQuery reference to your input field

note: between onclick and onfocus, the latter is the best event to handle because it is *device-independent*

note2: always use namespaced events (so you could safety unbind them later)

Comment: It’s not very maintainable to have the default value in your JavaScript like that, especially when it could just be in the HTML. Simply [use the standard HTML5 `placeholder` attribute and re-use that value for browsers that don’t support `@placeholder` natively yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265331/how-to-write-a-onfocus-event-in-jquery/4265393#4265393).

Comment: Since he didn't specify the doctype, you cannot assume he's using html5. AFAIK he could use html4. that solution is general and simply is the answer to his latest question

Comment: Browsers don’t really care about the DOCTYPE. You can have an HTML4 DOCTYPE and still use `@placeholder` just fine. Sure, the HTML won’t validate, but it’ll work just as it would with an HTML5 DOCTYPE. I’m not assuming he’s using HTML5; I’m saying he should.

Comment: I perfectly know that it would works anyway, BUT If he don't specify the doctype, then I don't think that my answer is a BAD answer. =)

Comment: If there’s a standardized way of doing things, there’s no need to rely on JavaScript all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Either

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

```
$(selector).focus(function);
```

Or, in case you dynamically load the content (ajax, etc)

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$(selector).live("focus",function);
```